# can't checkout the bootstrap v4-dev branch

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to checkout the bootstrap v4-dev branch. but not working.

my git version is: *git version 2.7.0.windows.1*

I already cloned the repository.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git (push)
```

execute *git fetch origin* output nothing.

```
$ git fetch origin

$ git branch -a
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

and got error when checkout obviously.

```
$ git checkout v4-dev
error: pathspec 'v4-dev' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout -b v4-dev origin/v4-dev
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'v4-dev' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/v4-dev' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

So where is wrong?

Comment: I re-clone the repository then `git checkout -b v4-dev origin/v4-dev` works. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not v4-dev. It is master. You should checkout as follows:

```
$ git checkout -b v4-dev origin/master
```

Comment: thanks. it works. but why *git branch -a*  doesn't show the *v4-dev*?

Comment: I can see all branches including v4-dev. Maybe you didn't fetch all data. Try to fetch origin again.

Comment: yes. I re-clone the repository and everything is fine. your answer is checkout the remote **master** branch to local branch **v4-dev**, that's not what i want. `git checkout -b v4-dev origin/v4-dev` is right. thanks anyway.

Comment: My answer is based on your question which does not contain the origin/v4-dev branch.  Now you can see the branch, ‘git checkout -b v4-dev origin/v4-dev’ is absolutely the right answer. :)